# Trouble traversing Visual Tree in C++/WinRT

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm implementing an app w/ Excel-style functionality where I have a ListBox of baskets, each containing  a ListBox of Items, each containing a StackPanel-nested Button inside it.

[XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvkKt.png), [What the layout looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PiEc.png)

Goal: I want to click on the button, such that the item entry (StackPanel) is highlighted via SelectedIndex(). I try to accomplish this in the [GotFocus="ItemGotFocus"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJciv.png) event handler, by traversing the visual tree to find the parent ListBox, so I can call SelectedIndex() on it.

However, I am getting errors whenever I call VisualTreeHelper::GetParent() or other functions from the namespapce in general:

Do I need to define a template definition somewhere, so it can figure out the type I want it to return, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: The reason for the error in your image is that you didn't add the corresponding header file when you use GetParent method. You could refer to the Important part in the document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started#a-cwinrt-quick-start) which says "Whenever you want to use a type from a Windows namespaces, you must `#include` the corresponding C++/WinRT Windows namespace header file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it worked!

Turns out I had included <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.h> in "pch.h", when what I really needed was <winrt/**Windows**.UI.Xaml.Media.h>.